# How to Batch Rename Photos but Keep Same Numbers

Tags: batch, rename, photos

I've been researching this for over an hour now. Bottom line is I want to keep the NUMBER when I rename the photos. Nearly every app or process wants to rename all photos starting with (1) or 1 or something to that degree.

If I have a picture titled Damar Trip 078, I want to rename it as Wedding 078. But if it's the 40th photo (due to deletions), I get Wedding 40 or Wedding (40). Bleh.

Surely there's an app or command prompt or something that can do this - I just can't find it.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: ...and what batch rename tools you've tried, for example? It sounds like you're attempting to use the wrong functionality; this is a string replace operation, not a numbering operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I understand your problem, But my solution works if you have these two things,

1. Windows 11.
2. All the Photos or files are Named starting with Damar Trip.

If you have

1. You need to install Microsoft PowerToys from Microsoft Store.
2. Activate PowerRename.
3. Select all the files you need to rename and right click to find PowerRename

Now you can replace all the names you can search for to any thing you want.
Only the names you selected will be changed and nothing more.

If you don't have Windows 11 you can copy the photos or files to a flash drive and find someone else's computer with Windows 11 and it still works.

Comment: Perfect! Not being familiar with PowerToys, this took me a little longer than expected. But I tested it, and it worked to perfection. Thank you, man!

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, this functionality is built-into the Finder.

Select the files you want to rename. Right click > Rename *n* items…

[image]

Choose the text to replace & that to replace it with.

[image]

Click Rename.
Done.

Comment: I have a Mac, but I prefer to keep everything on my PC. That's good to know, though, so thank you.